# Spring Boot with Postgres: After saving the identifier must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've just started with the whole Spring/JPA as a side project to build a local application and I'm trying to add a new entry in my database but I'm completely stuck on this error.
I've looked several other posts but to no avail.

On the DB side this is what my table currently looks like

```
CREATE TABLE ShopOwner (
    OwnerID SERIAL,
    VATNumber VARCHAR(20),
    OwnerName VARCHAR(20) ,
    OwnerLName VARCHAR(20)
);

ALTER TABLE ShopOwner
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_shopowner PRIMARY KEY (OwnerID);
```

while on java I have
shopowner.java

```
package invoicegenerator.Entities;


import javax.persistence.*;

@org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table

// @NamedQuery(name = "shopowner.findAll", query = "SELECT so FROM shopowner
// so")
@Entity
public class shopowner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ownerid;
    private String vatnumber;
    private String ownername;
    private String ownerlname;

    public shopowner() {

    }
    public shopowner(String vatnumber, String ownername, String ownerlname) {
        this.vatnumber = vatnumber;
        this.ownername = ownername;
        this.ownerlname = ownerlname;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "shopowner [ownerlname=" + ownerlname + ", ownername=" + ownername + ", vatnumber=" + vatnumber + "]";
    }
    public void setVATNumber (String VATNumber){
        this.vatnumber = VATNumber;
    }
    public String getVatnumber() {
        return vatnumber;
    }

    public long getOwnerid() {
        return ownerid;
    }

    public String getOwnername() {
        return ownername;
    }

    public void setOwnername(String ownername) {
        this.ownername = ownername;
    }

    public String getOwnerlname() {
        return ownerlname;
    }

    public void setOwnerlname(String ownerlname) {
        this.ownerlname = ownerlname;
    }

}
```

ShopOwnerRepository.java

```
package invoicegenerator.Repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import invoicegenerator.Entities.shopowner;

@Repository
public interface ShopOwnerRepository extends CrudRepository<shopowner, Long>{
}
```

Lastly this is my Main.java

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package invoicegenerator;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import invoicegenerator.Repositories.ShopOwnerRepository;
import invoicegenerator.Entities.shopowner;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Main{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    
  }
  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo (ShopOwnerRepository repository){
    return (args -> {
        shopowner so = new shopowner("A","b","c");
        repository.save(so);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the full error thrown in the console:

```
2022-07-30 15:33:26.410 ERROR 21583 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at invoicegenerator.Main.main(Main.java:25) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: After saving the identifier must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:364) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:161) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:75) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy60.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy60.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at invoicegenerator.Main.lambda$demo$0(Main.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2022-07-30 15:33:26.414  INFO 21583 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-30 15:33:26.417  INFO 21583 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If you need any more info I'll be editing this post.
Thanks to everyone.

Edit1: If I change (as suggested by @PrakherJindal)

```
private long ownerid
```

to

```
private Long ownerid
```

I get different errors such as:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at invoicegenerator.Main.main(Main.java:25) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute InsertRoot{entity=shopowner [ownerlname=c, ownername=b, vatnumber=A], idValueSource=NONE}
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:90) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DefaultAggregateChange.forEachAction(DefaultAggregateChange.java:127) ~[spring-data-relational-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:360) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:161) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:75) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy60.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy60.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at invoicegenerator.Main.lambda$demo$0(Main.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO "shopowner" ("ownerid", "ownerlname", "ownername", "vatnumber") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERRORE: null value in column "ownerid" of relation "shopowner" violates not-null constraint
  Dettaglio: La riga in errore contiene (null, A, b, c).; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: null value in column "ownerid" of relation "shopowner" violates not-null constraint
  Dettaglio: La riga in errore contiene (null, A, b, c).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:251) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:981) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.InsertStrategyFactory$DefaultInsertStrategy.execute(InsertStrategyFactory.java:87) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:77) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:65) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: null value in column "ownerid" of relation "shopowner" violates not-null constraint
  Dettaglio: La riga in errore contiene (null, A, b, c).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 56 common frames omitted

2022-07-30 16:16:58.759  INFO 23091 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-30 16:16:58.762  INFO 23091 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit2:
This is my build.gradle for dependencies

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.hibernate.orm" version "6.1.1.Final"
}

javafx {
    version = "18.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}


repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'

    //runtimeOnly files('/home/zen/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/lib/postgresql-42.4.0.jar')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'invoicegenerator.Main'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Can you try converting long to Long in your entity class

Comment: How do you want `ownerid` field to be filled?

Comment: @PrakherJindal just tried it, I'll edit the main post with the new error (Caused by: org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute InsertRoot{entity=shopowner [ownerlname=c, ownername=b, vatnumber=A], idValueSource=NONE})

Comment: @pholak it's supposed to be an auto incremented variable if that's what you're asking, so I'd just populate the other three fields

Comment: Ok, if it should be auto-incremented, you need to create a proper database column that will be able to do it. Which database are you using?

Comment: @pholak I'm using Postgres but I'm not really sure what you mean, by doing a simple Insert on shopowner it does auto-increment.

Comment: I have just copied your code and SQL and it works, values were inserted into my database without any error. Let me think.

Comment: Something may be wrong with your dependencies because the code works for me. Can you paste your pom.xml dependencies?

Comment: @pholak edited main post with my build.gradle file. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: seems like you are missing the setter for `ownerid` in the `shopowner` Entity class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal `build.gradle` file to perform the insert using `Main`, `Shopowner` and `ShopOwnerRepository`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

You can test if it works and later just add other required parts if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have a different error which is :
Description:

Parameter 0 of method demo in invoicegenerator.Main required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Look at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). example, it is very similar to your case and works fine, I also tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the `ShopOwner` table using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,` instead of using the `SERIAL` pseudotype.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE ShopOwner (
    OwnerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    VATNumber VARCHAR(20),
    OwnerName VARCHAR(20) ,
    OwnerLName VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to rebuild everything from scratch since I couldn't figure out what the issue was and finally got something to work with.

I'll post the main files cited in the OP in case it might be useful to anyone.

```
build.gradle


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.invoice'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.6'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
ShopOwner.java



package org.invoice;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "shopowner")
public class ShopOwner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ownerid;


    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String vatnumber;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String ownername;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String ownerlname;


    public ShopOwner(String vatnumber, String ownername, String ownerlname) {
        this.vatnumber = vatnumber;
        this.ownername = ownername;
        this.ownerlname = ownerlname;
    }

    public ShopOwner(){

    }
    public String getVatnumber() {
        return vatnumber;
    }

    public void setVatnumber(String vatnumber) {
        this.vatnumber = vatnumber;
    }
    public long getOwnerid() {
        return ownerid;
    }


    public String getOwnername() {
        return ownername;
    }

    public void setOwnername(String ownername) {
        this.ownername = ownername;
    }

    public String getOwnerlname() {
        return ownerlname;
    }

    public void setOwnerlname(String ownerlname) {
        this.ownerlname = ownerlname;
    }

    public void setOwnerid(long ownerid) {
        this.ownerid = ownerid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShopOwner{" +
                "ownerid=" + ownerid +
                ", vatnumber='" + vatnumber + '\'' +
                ", ownername='" + ownername + '\'' +
                ", ownerlname='" + ownerlname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
ShopOwnerRepository

package org.invoice;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ShopOwnerRepository extends CrudRepository<ShopOwner, Long> {
    List<ShopOwner> findShopOwnerByVatnumber(String VATNumber);
    ShopOwner findShopOwnerByOwnerid(long ownerID);
}
```

```
Resources/application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/InvoiceGenerator
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Thank you everyone who lent a hand, much appreciated.